# Validação de Formulário com indexOf()

Tags: javascript, validação, indexof

Sei que tem como validar com HTML5 ou CSS, mas é só por curiosidade: Achei um codigo na net que verifica se a sintaxe de um e-mail digitado está correto:

```
if(document.dados.email.value=="" || document.dados.email.value.indexOf('@') == -1 || document.dados.email.value.indexOf('.')  == -1 ) 
        {
```

E funciona. O problema é que eu não consigo entender como esse valor condicional "-1" pode ser legítimo se não existe valor de array ou string negativo.

Entretanto me baseando por um fiapo de lógica eu supus que "-1" significasse "não existe", dai eu modifiquei este para `<0` e depois para `<1` e os dois também funcionaram.

Poderiam, por favor, me dar uma explicação mais clara sobre esse caso?

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema pode marcar como aceite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `indexOf()` existe para [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) e [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), funciona basicamente da mesma maneira:

<sub>(Note que o método em Arrays é mais recente e só disponivel no IE9+)</sub>

- `-1` se não existir na array ou string o valor procurado
- de `0` e para a frente é para caso de existir e aí o numero é a posição do elemento na String e Array

No seu caso, quando tem `document.dados.email.value.indexOf('@') == -1` essa verificação dá `true` se não existir uma arroba (`@`) na String.

No caso de `document.dados.email.value.indexOf('@')` dar `0` a validação deveria falhar pois isso seria um email tipo `@gmail.com` sem "nome de utilizador", por isso a sua ideia de fazer a verificação com `< 1` faz muito sentido.

Comment: Perfeito man. O que tu acha desse aprimoramento que eu fiz? http://jsfiddle.net/fmts9q4h/. A premissa é que se o "@" estiver ok, tem que haver um "." a pelo menos 2 casas depois do "@", pra nao ficar "@.". Agora está validando perfeitamente sem brechas. A condição de "" não é necessária.

Comment: fui tentar adicionar esse essa condição no mesmo if "indice.lastIndexOf('.') == indice.length". É para testar se no e-mail o ultimo caractere é um "."; mas não está funcionando, o resto está, veja http://jsfiddle.net/sfd6t9co/

Comment: esqueceu de mim?

Comment: @ropbla9 bom dia. Desculpe tenho estado cheio de trabalho com o novo site do MooTools. Vou dar uma olhada daqui a pouco e já comento a sua ideia.

Comment: ok. Eu queria conversar inbox com você mas não consigo.

Comment: @ropbla9 vou estar aqui uns minutos: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18484/tempore

Comment: Estou por aqui ^ de novo...